# Errors involving matrix operations in Flink programs

Tags: matrix, flink-streaming

The flink program runs normally locally, but uploading to the server after packaging always fails, and the following message is displayed:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netlib/blas/Dgemm
        at com.github.fommil.netlib.F2jBLAS.dgemm(F2jBLAS.java:96)
        at breeze.linalg.operators.DenseMatrixMultiplyStuff$implOpMulMatrix_DMD_DMD_eq_DMD$.apply(DenseMatrixOps.scala:63)
        at breeze.linalg.operators.DenseMatrixMultiplyStuff$implOpMulMatrix_DMD_DMD_eq_DMD$.apply(DenseMatrixOps.scala:48)
        at breeze.linalg.ImmutableNumericOps$class.$times(NumericOps.scala:135)
        at breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix.$times(DenseMatrix.scala:53)
        at com.zte.flink.machinelearning.robustRegressionAlgorithm$.IRLS(robustRegressionAlgorithm.scala:32)
        at com.zte.flink.machinelearning.robustRegressionAlgorithm$.predict(robustRegressionAlgorithm.scala:88)
        at com.zte.flink.test$.main(test.scala:21)
        at com.zte.flink.test.main(test.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:427)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:813)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:287)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:213)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1050)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1126)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1754)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1126)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netlib.blas.Dgemm
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that org.netlib.blas.Dgemm is in your local CLASSPATH, but is not on the server's CLASSPATH. You'll need to either build a fat jar that includes this library and then submit the far jat to the cluster (recommended), or put it in the lib directory of all of the flink servers.

See [the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/projectsetup/dependencies.html) for more details on how to handle dependencies for your Flink applications.